# AngularJS Targeting elements in current iteration in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am sure this question has been answered numerous times in one form or another, however I am not sure what to search for to find the solution.

Say we have a simple ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <input type="text" value="{{item.name}}">
   <a ng-click="getTxtBoxVal(whatDoIPassInHere)">Get Text Box Value</a>
</div>
```

in the javaScript file:

```
   function $scope.getTxtBoxVal(val) {
       alert(val)
   }
```

Basically I want to know what should get passed in the `whatDoIPassInHere` parameter, which in jquery would be something like: `$(this).siblings(input).val()`

---

I do have a workaround which is to give each textbox a unique ID:

`<input type="text" id="myTextBox_{{index}}" value="{{item.name}}`>

and target it with the unique ID, but I am sure there's a more elegant way to handle this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background is a great read if you are coming from jquery. But to give you a little direction: You are going to want to use `ng-model="item.name"` instead of `value=...`. Then you would just pass `item` in place of `whatDoIPassInHere`.

Comment: @csbarnes thanks for the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not associating the input with a model, so angular has no idea how to reference the value. [See this plunkr for how to accomplish what you are asking](http://plnkr.co/edit/A78r4KBBw9ccQhB7YPaK?p=preview).

**Controller**

```
$scope.things = [
    {
      'name': 'apple',
      'value': '12',
      'isTasty': true
    },
    {
      'name': 'tire',
      'value': '7',
      'isTasty': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'carrot',
      'value': '9',
      'isTasty': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'cake',
      'value': '1',
      'isTasty': true
    }
  ];

  $scope.getVal = function (value) {
    alert(value);
  };
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in things">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" value="{{item.name}}">
      <a href="#" ng-click="getVal(item.name)">Get Text Box Value</a>
    </div>
```